# How to check != null in Cassandra using datastax DevCenter?

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cql

I've tried different cases:

```
where ip != NULL
where ip <> NULL
where ip IS NOT NULL
```

but it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 1):

it works by tricky ears feint:

```
where ip >= ''
```